# apex:inputText and apex:outputLink issue

Tags: visualforce, inputtext, outputlink

I am using inputText to capture user input and then this input needs to be passed to a URL as a parameter. I am using the following code:

```
<apex:form >
<apex:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="true"> 
    <apex:inputText value="{!searchText}" id="textsearch" rendered="true" />
    <apex:outputLink id="link"  value="/apex/VFPageName">Search
        <apex:param value="{!searchText}" name="searchParameter"/>
    </apex:outputLink>
</apex:panelGrid>
```

Controller code

```
public string searchText{get;set;}
```

The problem here is that when I enter a value in the text box and press the link the redirect is being performed but the parameter value is blank. 
Another strange thing is if I enter a value and press enter and then click on the link then the parameter is being passed with the correct value.

What I am looking out is for normal functionality to work i.e. user enters text and on click of the link the user is redirected with the parameter set correctly

Please advice

Comment: How does this pass the parameter to your page?  It seems like something is missing in your controller.

Answer (score 4):

You can not pass searchText into your link, because it will be always blank when you load your page. I would do more something like :

```
<apex:form >
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="true"> 
      <apex:inputText value="{!searchText}" id="textsearch" rendered="true" />
      <apex:outputLink id="link"  action="{!processLinkClick}">Search</apex:outputLink>
   </apex:panelGrid>
 </apex:form>

public string searchText{get;set;}
 public PageReference processLinkClick() {
    return new PageReference('/apex/VFPageName?searchParameter='+searchText);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am thinking, based on what you described, that you need to do something like this:

```
<apex:form >
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="true"> 
      <apex:inputText value="{!searchText}" id="textsearch" rendered="true" />
      <apex:outputLink id="link"  action="{!processLinkClick}">Search
         <apex:param value="{!searchText}" assignTo"{sText}"" name="searchParameter"/>
      </apex:outputLink>
   </apex:panelGrid>
 </apex:form>

 public String sText {get; set;}
 public PageReference processLinkClick() {
    System.debug('sText: '+sText);
    return new PageReference('/apex/VFPageName?searchParameter='+sText);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce page :

```
<apex:form>
  <apex:panelGrid columns="2" rendered="true"> 
    <apex:inputText value="{!searchText}" id="textsearch" rendered="true" />
<apex:outputLink id="link"  value="/apex/VFPageName">Search
    <apex:param assignTo="{!SText}" value={!searchText} name="searchParameter"/>
</apex:outputLink>
```

And change a little bit  in Controller Code  -

public string SText{get;set;}